# C++ threads producer consumer

Tags: c++, multithreading, producer-consumer

I need to implement a piggy bank simulation where clients can either deposit or withdraw money from. The clients should be represented as threads, and the piggy bank is an integer variable. I need to create two functions called producer and consumer, which should be able to deposit or withdraw an amount defined by a parameter. Restrictions are that the consumer should only withdraw if there is enough money in the piggy bank. If not, it should wait for the piggy bank to fill up.

The consumer and producer have to simultaneously access the piggy bank, and add or remove random amounts.

I'm having troubles with this. I'm new to both c++ and threads. I have looked at different consumer producer solutions, but I can't find anything that helps.

This is my code so far. I reckon the structure is correct, but

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <thread>
 #include <mutex>
 #include <condition_variable>

 using namespace std;

 int piggybank;
 mutex mlock;
 condition_variable sem;
 bool available = false;

 void consumer(int amount){
     unique_lock<mutex> lck(mlock);
     sem.wait(lck);
     piggybank -= amount;
 }

 void producer(int amount){
     unique_lock<mutex> lck(mlock);
     piggybank += amount;
     //available = piggybank > 50;
     sem.notify_all();
 }

 int main() {
     piggybank = 0;

     thread cons(consumer, rand()%50+1);
     thread prod(producer, rand()%50+1);

     prod.join();
     cons.join();

     return 0;
 }
```

I need some sort of condition, but I don't know how to use the conditional variable.

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Use the overload of `condition_variable.wait()` that takes a predicate that says the wait should unblock when `piggybank` has enough value.

Comment: Also - just a style comment: I don't like the name `sem` for the `condition_variable`.  It seems misleading to me since it's not a semaphore.

Comment: You should also be aware that since currently the producer thread only adds a random value once to the piggybank, if that amount is less than the random amount the consumer wants to withdraw, the consumer will wait forever for the piggyback to get enough value.

Comment: When developers say "producer/consumer", they usually are talking about an architecture in which producers place _distinct objects_ or _distinct values_ into a queue, and consumers remove the objects/values and do something with them.  To call somebody who deposits money into a bank account a "producer" and, somebody who withdraws it a "consumer' is streching that metaphor somewhat beyond its usual bounds.

Answer (score 1):

One problem you could run in to:  Your code does nothing to guarantee that the consumer will be waiting in the `sem.wait(lck)` call *before* the producer calls `sem.notify()`.  If the producer gets there first, then the notification will be lost, and the consumer will never wake up.

Also, You should always use a loop to wait on a condition variable, and it should always test the condition for which you are waiting.

```
while ( piggybank < amount ) {
    sem.wait();
}
piggybank -= amount;
```

The test ensures that the consumer won't wait for a notification that never will come if the producer got there first.

You could say `if` instead of `while`, but the loop is a good habit to learn.  You will need it later when you write a multi-consumer program because in that case, one consumer could wake up and discover that another consumer woke up first and took the money (or the task, or whatever it is that they are consuming.)

Comment: Actually - you can't say `if` instead of `while` because the wait is permitted to return spuriously.  And even if the unblock isn't spurious, the consumer would need to still check that enough was added to `piggybank` to allow the 'withdrawal'.

Comment: And a side note: C++14 's `condition_variable` supports an overload where the condition to be tested can be passed to the `wait()` function - the looping is handled by the library function making the client code a bit cleaner.